# Printing Reversed linked list iteratively

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, iteration

I am currently writing a program that has a function that prints a linked list in reverse.

I need to print the reverse of what this code prints using the iterative approach.

EDIT: It is a single linked list.

Thanks in advance.

```
void print_backward_iteration(NODE *ptr) {
    NODE *last, *current;

    last = NULL;

    printf("\n");

    while (ptr != last) {
        current = ptr;

        while (current -> next != last) {
            current= current -> next;
        }

        printf("%d  ", current -> data);
        last = current;
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* declaration of structure */
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

/* declaration of functions */
NODE* insert_node(NODE *ptr, NODE *new);
NODE* find_node(NODE *ptr, int n);
NODE* delete_node(NODE *ptr, int n, int *success_flag_ptr);
void print_backward_iteration(NODE *ptr);
void print_backward_recursion(NODE *ptr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int choice, x, flag_success;
    NODE *ptr, *new, *result;

    ptr = NULL;

    do {
        printf("\n1.\tInsert Integer into linked list\n");
        printf("2.\tFind integer in linked list\n");
        printf("3.\tDelete integer from linked list\n");
        printf("4.\tPrint out integers backward using the iterative strategy\n");
        printf("5.\tPrint out integers backward using the recursive strategy\n");
        printf("6.\tQuit\n");
        printf("\nEnter 1,2,3,4,5, or 6: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("\nPlease enter an integer: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            new->data = x;
            ptr = insert_node(ptr, new);
            printf("\nNode Inserted with value of %d.\n", ptr->data);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\nPlease enter an integer: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            result = find_node(ptr, x);

            if (result == NULL) {
                printf("\nValue could not be found.\n");
            } else {
                printf("\nValue %d was found.\n", x);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("\nPlease enter an integer: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            ptr = delete_node(ptr, x, &flag_success);

            if (result == NULL) {
                printf("\nValue could not be found.\n");
            } else {
                printf("\nValue %d was deleted.\n", x);
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            print_backward_iteration(ptr);
            break;

        case 5:
            printf("\n");
            print_backward_recursion(ptr);
            printf("\n");
            break;

        case 6:
            printf("\nThank you for using this program.\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nInvalid Choice. Please try again.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    while (choice != 6);

    printf("\n*** End of Program ***\n");
    return 0;
}

/* definition of function insert_node */
NODE* insert_node(NODE *ptr, NODE *new) {
    new -> next = ptr;
    return new;
}

/* definition of function find_node */
NODE* find_node(NODE *ptr, int n) {
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr->data == n) {
            return ptr;
        } else {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

/* definition of function delete_node */
NODE* delete_node(NODE *ptr, int n, int *success_flag_ptr) {
    NODE *temp = NULL;

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        *success_flag_ptr = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (ptr -> data == n) {     
        temp = ptr->next;  
        free(ptr);         
        *success_flag_ptr = 1;
        return temp;
    } else
        ptr->next = delete_node(ptr->next,n,success_flag_ptr); 

    return ptr;
}

/* definition of function print_backward_iteration */
void print_backward_iteration(NODE *ptr) {
    NODE *last, *current;

    last = NULL;

    printf("\n");

    while (ptr != last) {
        current = ptr;

        while (current != last) {
            current =  current -> next;
        }

        printf("%d  ", current -> data);
        last = current -> next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

/* definition of function print_backward_recursion */
void print_backward_recursion(NODE *ptr) {
    NODE *last, *current;

    last = NULL;

    while (ptr != last) {
        current = ptr;
        printf("%d  ", current -> data);
        print_backward_recursion(current -> next);
        last = current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right before I delete my answer I have to ask: how do you have code to print a list using a nested while-loop in an O(N^2) algorithm iteratively, and a function that prints it in reverse recursively, and yet did *not* have the code to walk the list, beginning to end, in *regular* order of head-to-tail? Hmmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void print_Linked_List_iteration(NODE *ptr)
{

  printf("\n");

  while (ptr != NULL)
  {

      printf("%d  ", ptr->data);
      ptr = ptr->next;
  }

  printf("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE** - I'm keeping the code below on the off-chance someone looking to actually reverse-print a linked list sans-recursion using any of the methods provided can get *some* kinda of use out of them. In the meantime, the OP's **real** question was effectively:

> "How to I print a linked list in head-to-tail order?"

Who saw *that* coming? Anyway,

```
void print_node_list(const NODE* p)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (;p;printf("%d ",p->data),p=p->next);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Yeah, it was that simple.

---

**Now-Near-Worthless Reverse-Print Discussion**

Complying with your requirement of this being an **iterative** solution, and more importantly, *assuming your lists order **unchanged** after this operation is complete*, you can either:

1. Manage a node pointer stack in your iteration, pushing pointers as you single-pass the list traveral, then popping pointers off the stack to print the reverse. Requires two passes (one through the list, one through the stack). There are multiple options for managing such a stack; two are presented below.
2. Perform a simple reverse/print/reverse. Requires three passes (one for the reverse, one for the print, and one for the undo-reverse).

The former of these offers the advantage of keeping the list constant (no node-reversals are done) at the price of the space required to manage the stack. The latter of these offers the benefit of no additional space requirements, but at the cost of three-passes on the list, and requiring the list be allowed to be modified, though temporarily.

Which you choose is up to you.

**Local Stack Implementation**: (2 passes, 2*N*sizeof(pointer) space)

```
void print_reverse_node_list(const NODE* head)
{
    struct stnode
    {
        struct stnode* next;
        const NODE* node;
    } *st = NULL;

    while (head)
    {
        struct stnode* p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        if (p)
        {
            p->next = st;
            p->node = head;
            st = p;
            head = head->next;
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Could not allocate space for reverse-print.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // walks stack, popping off nodes and printing them.
    printf("\n");
    while (st)
    {
        struct stnode* p = st;
        st = st->next;
        printf("%d ", p->node->data);
        free(p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Another Local Stack Implementation** (2-passes, N*sizeof(pointer) space)

```
void print_reverse_node_list(const NODE* head)
{
    NODE const **ar = NULL;
    size_t i=0;
    while (head)
    {
        // reallocate pointer array
        NODE const **tmp = realloc(ar, ++i * sizeof(*tmp));
        if (tmp)
        {
            ar = tmp;           // remember new array
            ar[i-1] = head;     // last index gets the ptr
            head = head->next;  // advance to next node
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Could not allocate space for reverse-print.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // print nodes from [i-1] to [0]
    printf("\n");
    for (; i!=0; printf("%d ", ar[--i]->data));
    printf("\n");
    // don't forget to release the block (NULL is ok)
    free(ar);
}
```

**Reverse/Print/Reverse Implementation**: (3 passes, no additional space)

```
// print a node list.
void print_node_list(const NODE* p)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (;p;printf("%d ",p->data),p=p->next);
    printf("\n");
}

// reverses a linked list in-place.
void reverse_node_list(NODE **headp)
{
    if (!headp || !*headp)
        return;

    NODE *ptr = *headp, *next = NULL, *prev = NULL;
    while (ptr)
    {
        next = ptr->next;      // remember next node (1)
        ptr->next = prev;      // wire next to prev
        prev = ptr;            // set prev to current
        ptr = next;            // move to remembered next (see 1)
    }

    *headp = prev;
}

void print_reverse_node_list(NODE* head)
{
    reverse_node_list(&head);
    print_node_list(head);
    reverse_node_list(&head);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the nature of the list:

- If this is a doubly-linked list, simply iterate in reverse.
- If this is a singly-linked list, you are going to have to maintain a stack yourself, basically doing what a recursive solution would do, but iteratively. This is essentially the same as making a reverse copy of the list (this can be done iteratively), and printing the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the list is singly linked because otherwise the problem would be trivial. I would make a copy of the list in reverse order then print that. Basically;

```
 void print_reverse_iteration(NODE *ptr)
 {
        NODE *previous = head;
        NODE *current = head;
        bool trailing = false; //used to ensure we're on head->next before we begin moving prev
        last = NULL;

        printf("\n");

        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
               current->next = previous;
               if (trailing)
                   previous = previous->next;
               else
               {
                   trailing = true;
                   current->next = NULL; // this is now the end of the list so we need to set it's next pointer to null to ensure we halt in other methods that rely on node->next == NULL
                }
               current = current->next
         }

         //the list is now in reverse order. print it with your regular print method.
         normalPrint(current);
        // current is the head of this temporary list so pass it current.    

    }
```

Comment: Why traverse the same list twice (once to build the reverse and once to print) for a simple print operation?

Comment: @MihaiStancu I'm pretty sure that's the only way to do it without creating a stack or using recursion. And printing a singly linked list in reverse order without recursion is not a simple operation.

Comment: @MihaiStancu It's funny you criticize this answer but upvote an answer that ignores the question entirely.

Comment: I upvoted because it gave me clarity on the problem. I didn't downvote your answer. I was trying to offer constructive criticism. Let's not take it any further.

Comment: I'd go with the pointer stack as per WhozCraig's answer, creating a secondary reversed list has the disadvantages of both approaches, requires extra space and extra time.

Comment: My only criticism of this answer is it ultimately reverses the list *and keeps it that way*. This isn't making a copy; its reversing the *existing* list direction. Worse, the original head-pointer will now reference the *last* node in the list. Unless this reversal-of-fortune is undone with a third pass before the function exists the head pointer will reference the *last* node, `head->next` will point to NULL, and the rest of the list will be leaked. (that `head` is not even the parameter name of the incoming list pointer (`ptr`) is minor compared to the rest of this).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah that is doing it in place, but doing it with a copy wouldn't be much different. I was too lazy to write out all the code (thus my current == head). It wouldn't take much effort to modify the code to make a copy instead. The algorithm is all there.

Comment: @MihaiStancu a stack is a singly linked list. There is no difference in the amount of space or time it would take to make a stack verses a list.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly way to do it, abusing the function call stack:

```
void print_reverse_iteration(NODE *ptr)
{
    if (ptr != NULL) 
    {
        print_reverse_iteration( ptr->next);
        printf( "%d  ", ptr->data);
    }
}

print_reverse_iteration( head);
puts( "");
```

Will only work for short lists that don't overflow the stack.

Comment: Ah, missed that requirement...  I'll update my solution to be, "if you need to walk your list in reverse, it should be a doubly-linked list".  %-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    void PrintBackwards (node * head)
     {
       if(head)
        {
          PrintBackwards(head->next);
          printf("%d",head->data);
        }
       return;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java solution using stack:

```
public void printReverseUsingStack(Node head){

    if(head == null){
        return;
    }
    Node current = head;
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();

    while(current != null){
        s.push(current.data);
        current = current.next;
    }
    while(!s.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print(s.pop() + " -> ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Output will be: 10 -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 ->